# proper way of calling the functions during init in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting error method1 () is undefined. What is the proper way to invoke a method during init?

```
 gdmsDashboard.controller('DashboardController', '$scope') {

        $scope.Msg = "";

        (function init() {
            $scope.method1 ();
            method1 ();
            this.method1 ();

        })();

        $scope.method1 = function () { 
          //
        }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `init`, `run` method ?

Comment: You need to learn `variable hoisting concept`

Comment: $scope.logOut function needs to be created first before you can call it using the controller setup you have.

Comment: I guess the question is why are you initing a logout function?  Are you logging the user out when the controller is called?

Comment: You need to define the `$scope.logout` before the iife statement.

Comment: I have renamed logout to method1 as it was causing confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand [variable hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) concept

Just to make your code work do this

```
$scope.method1 = function () { 
          //
        }
(function init() {
            $scope.method1();
})();
```